# Kendo Scheduler DatePicker events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datepicker

How can I set event for **Kendo Scheduler** Start and End date DatePicker control?
I want to put some logic when Start or End date changes from DatePicker control but I don't know how to do.

I tried to bind event like below but it is not working for me:

```
start: { 
   type: "date",
   from: "StartDate",
   validation: { required: true },
   event: { change: "onStartDateChange('start')" }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select those `DatePicker` and add your new function when scheduler triggering `edit` event.

here is some code snippet you need to add

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  edit: scheduler_edit // add on scheduler edit events
  //remove for clarity
});
```

next you need to find `DatePicker` components using jquery and bind it with new function. While `Scheduler` edit popup window provide with 2 type different datepicker you need to select carefully whether as `DatePicker` or `DateTimePicker`

```
function scheduler_edit(e) {
  console.log("edit");
  var startDatePicker = $("input[name=start][data-role=datepicker]").data().kendoDatePicker;
  startDatePicker.bind("change", newFuncForDatePicker);
}

function newFuncForDatePicker(e) {
   console.log(this.value());
}
```

for complete sample, you can look into this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/UtOSU)

Comment: Your dojo is not loading.

Comment: dojo not found `Snippet not found
The snippet may have been deleted by the author,
or the URL might be incorrect.`

Answer (score 0):

I think Your datePicker is not bind in kendo scheduler.If you have change some date and append this date in another datePicker you can use like this example
  This is my edit function you can use edit function or others function as you like:

```
 edit: function (e) {
        //get date from event
         var getDateFromEvent = e.event.start;//or you can use different types of date like that
         var datePicker = $("[name=signUpDueDate]").data("kendoDatePicker");
         datePicker.value(getDateFromEvent).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));                                         
         datePicker.trigger("change");
};
```

This is your controller Then you can use html like that

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group">
   <div data-container-for="earlySignupDate">
      <input id="signUpDueDate" name="signUpDueDate" class="pull-left" type="text" data-type="date" data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: SignUpDueDate" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  edit: function(e)
  {
    // clone for input[name=end]
    e.container.find("input[name=start]")
     .data()
     .kendoDateTimePicker.bind("change", function(e) {
        var value = this.value(); 
        // value has the new datetime
        console.log(value);
    });
  }
});  
</script>
```

Se my dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@svejdo1/AWoNU